# Xcode 10 Server: React Native RCTWebSocket libfishook.a remove and add again

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode-server

I'm trying to make a bot to continuously integrate my React Native XCode project. After upgrading to XCode 10, I have faced many problems like

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14382
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19569

which were previously not there in XCode 9 Server. I have finally fixed the first one (the configure.h one) by adding some custom scripts in the prebuild trigger, and aware about how to fix the second problem (the libfishhook.a problem) in my actual project using XCode's GUI. Is there a way to do it in command line, so that I can add that too.

Alternatively, should I have been talking a completely different approach to fix my problem (I didn't update any libaries, just my XCode and this happened, is there a way to use the legacy build system in XCode Server?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19569#issuecomment-399652331) comment solved it for me.

I found this issue to be quite persistent so I created a directory called `/files/ios/` and placed `libfishhook.a` inside of here.

I then created an `npm` script which I could run to automate the copying of the file:

`"copy:fishhook": "cp ./files/ios/libfishhook.a ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket"`

Whilst we're on the subject of trying to fix Xcode 10 issues with React Native, here are a few more I've had to use:

- `"fix:config.h": "cd ./node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4 && ./configure && make && make install"`
- `"fix:darwin": "cd node_modules/react-native && scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh && cd third-party/glog-0.3.4/ && ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh"`

You'll need to change `glog-0.3.4` to your version.

Comment: Don't worry, even I didn't update `react-native` yet, so even I'm on `glog-0.3.4` , haha

Comment: Confirmed working after copying the file "libfishhook.a" and cp-ing it in the prebuild trigger script

Comment: ended up running into all 3 of these issues. thx for the smart idea of using npm to make it easier to fix when it arises.